# T-SQL ISNULL() Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I have this clause on a join in a stored procedure I inherited:

```
WHERE a.is_active = 1
AND b.due_date <= ISNULL(@due_date_limit, b.due_date)
```

How would I re-write this to remove the ISNULL as it's causing severe performance problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in this instance, i would have an if statement, checking @due_date_limit

```
IF (@due_date_limit IS NULL)
BEGIN
    ...
    WHERE   a.is_active = 1 --not required to compare b.due_date <= b.due_date
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ...
    WHERE   a.is_active = 1
    AND     b.due_date <= @due_date_limit
END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AND @due_date_limit IS NULL OR b.due_date <= @due_date_limit
```

but I'm not so sure it would be that much faster.

Comment: An index isn't a concern - even if one existed, the index would only be used in the 2nd half.  It's far better than the ISNULL/COALESCE suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause for poor performance with this type of query is because the optimizer can't be sure what the typically value of @due_date_limit will be for most queries.  Often the plan generated and re-used by subsequent executions favor the case where the value is null.

As of SQL 2005 you can guide the optimiser using the "OPTIMIZE FOR" option:-

```
WHERE a.is_active = 1
AND b.due_date <= ISNULL(@due_date_limit, b.due_date)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@due_date_limit = '09/01/2009'))
```

Comment: If the parameter is null, why would you still want to compare values?  You don't, so don't use ISNULL/COALESCE for optional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

is there an index on due_Date?  If not add one and then check the performance.  If there already is, then Change to two separate statements

```
  If @due_date_limit is null
    Select [stuff]
    From Table
  Else
    Select [stuff]
    From Table  
    Where b.due_date <= @due_date_limit
```

But realize that not filtering (when @due_date_limit is null), or filtering using a <= can potentially return a substantial number of records that will eliminate any opportunity to use an index and will require a complete table scan. This may be what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

@due_date_limit is a stored procedure variable so it can be factored out from this query all together:

```
if (@due_date_limit is NULL) 
   <run query that works when @due_date_limit is NULL>
else 
   <run query that works when @due_date_limit is NOT NULL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
COALESCE(@due_date_limit, b.due_date)
```

may help

Comment: This will handle things gracefully, but it's a waste to perform a 1 = 1 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Since `@due_date_limit` is a stored procedure variable, you can just check it for `NULL` before the query and set it to a default value if need be, thus eliminating the ISNULL check in the `WHERE` clause.

```
IF (@due_date_limit IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @due_date_limit = '09/01/2009';
END
```

and then your `WHERE` clause would simply look like this:

```
WHERE a.is_active = 1
AND b.due_date <= @due_date_limit
```

Comment: astander's answer is a better solution if you need it to be the same as the column record to meet the `<=` operator condition, otherwise set if before the query like this since it'll be faster and there's no check.